# Does BlackBerry OS version 4.x support jQuery?

Tags: jquery, blackberry

Does BlackBerry OS version 4.x support jQuery? If it not supported, then how do I write a web application for BlackBerry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the second to last page in the slideshow [Testing Mobile JavaScript](http://www.slideshare.net/jeresig/testing-mobile-javascript), it seems that BlackBerry OS v4.x should be treated as B grade browser, meaning that you can't expect that everything works.

Answer (score 2):

As Jan said, jQuery is 'technically' supported by Blackberry OS 4.x, however certain things simply don't work, including media queries. You should be able to develop a pretty reasonable jQuery-based page that will display fairly well, however you do have to be careful not to use any plugins that require this missing functionality.